# Is there any negative connotation to the word SpoonTalk or Spoon

Tags: meaning, connotation

This is my first question here. It is not exactly related to English usage.

-- Providing more details as suggested by John--

I am currently building a Software product and have named it SpoonTalk.

It is an Email Marketing Tool and will be used by businesses to send email newsletters to their customers.

I find the name easy to remember and interesting but English is not my native tongue and I dont really know if there is any negative connotation to the word SpoonTalk or Spoon.

So basically I ask the native English speakers if the word SpoonTalk is acceptable? Or should I look for something else.

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: To start with: Google the phrase, and also the neologism. https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22spoontalk%22  https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22spoon+talk%22

Comment: As long as it's not "[spooning](http://www.wikihow.com/Spoon-Someone) and talking" it should be fine. And I wouldn't consider it derogatory in any case :)

Comment: As a side issue, does the world *really* need more marketing email spam? sigh

Comment: _spoon_ is also slang for _idiot_, which might not be great. http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/s.htm

Comment: Please visit the link I posted which also uses the term *spoon* but as for your suggestion   **SpoonTalk** (written as one word), I doubt anyone would strongly object or snigger about it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I visited the link.. Spooning means "cuddling" "initmacy" etc.. so its not vulgar in any sense correct?

Comment: @Frank So would SpoonTalk imply talking with an idiot.. or something like that?

Comment: @MarvMills Does the world need more Spam?.. No!!  Does the world need more Software Tools?.. Maybe!! I wont know unless I try ;-)

Comment: To answer your question as to whether it's vulgar, I wouldn't say so. But *spooning* and *to spoon somebody* is a well-known expression to describe an intimate  love making position.

Comment: It was one of the first things that came into my head - two uses of _spoon_, an idiot and to kick a ball badly. I'd never heard of the sexual position. It doesn't look like many people are aware of the _idiot_ definition from the responses you've got so far.

Comment: @Frank Yes, football/soccer shot also came to mind, it's used in Italian as well. It describes how the ball slowly curves and falls behind the goalkeeper (usually). [animated Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuhjB5dBBeU)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  So I can safely assume that no one will get offended with the name.. Thanks a lot for taking time to answer..

Comment: Ankit - Do bear in mind, you asked for negatives, which made us all think negatively. SilverSpoon sugar (http://www.silverspoon.co.uk/) is very common in the UK and I doubt anyone thinks twice about it's name, but of course, there are things one cannot foresee: Ayds slimming chocolate for one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayds

Comment: @Frank.. That cleared it for me :-)... I just wanted to make sure that SpoonTalk will not sound vulgar / offensive / dumb.  So I can safely assume it wont fall into any of the above categories.. right :-)

Comment: I think you are probably fairly safe.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the inputs.. StackExchange Rocks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no negative connotation, in general.

But you might get better feedback if you can privide more information.

For example, *nova* has no negative connotation in Spanish. But Chevrolet made a mistake marketing a car with that name in Spanish-speaking markets, because *no va* means *no go.*

Comment: It actually reminds me of Spoon River:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoon_River_Anthology

Comment: @jim SpoonTalk is an Email Marketing tool... It will used by businesses to send Email Newsletters to their customers.

Answer (score 0):

*Spoon* has a connotation which may be undesirable in a business context.

> **spoon** *verb*
>
> ​2. [no object] informal , dated (Of two people) behave in an amorous way; kiss and cuddle:
>   *I saw them spooning on the beach*
>
> 2.1 (Of two people) lie close together sideways and front to back, so as to fit together like spoons.
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spoon?searchDictCode=all)

Comment: The first law of marketing: Never associate a brand or product with sex, intimacy, pleasure? O.O There's also *spoon-fed,* *[born with a] silver spoon,* *spoonerism,* but in all that, can we confidently say that an especially positive or negative connotation is likely to be carried for a significant number of people? Not that I can see.

Comment: @Jim I haven't said whether the connotation is positive or negative. I've pointed it out, as the OP may not know about it. Whether it's undesirable or not is another matter, and only he can know that.

Comment: @AndrewLeach So when you hear the word SpoonTalk.. what is the first thing that comes to mind? Does the word sound vulgar / unprofessional?

Comment: My meaning of *spoon* here would certainly come to mind while wondering why you chose that name.

Comment: The first thing that *spoon* says to me is the cutlery "tool" used for either soft or liquid foods, it's only when someone specifically asks what other meanings are there would the dictionary's second definition spring to mind